# What app is org.codeaurora.snapcam?

Tags: applications, google-account

I found this app with package `org.codeaurora.snapcam` showing up on my Google Activity. It say I used it, but also it doesn't show any details of what it is. It just shows details of my phone. I have Hot Pepper VLE5 phone and also a Samsung A20 which my husband uses but were on the same Google account on both phones.

My husband thinks it is a secret app that I use to hide things like messages and pictures. I love my husband very much and I know that is not true. I did some research of it but there was not many accurate answers. What I understood is that it's a camera app called camera apk, but I wouldn't know if it's that. I have seen a lot of apps on Google Play called Snapcam, but that is a photo editor and i don't use those kind of apps. So it can't be that.

I just don't know why this `org.codeaurora.snapcam` shows up on my Google activity saying I used it. I really need to know what this is. I'm so confused I would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: `snapcam` is SnapdragonCamera app: https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/platform/packages/apps/SnapdragonCamera. Snapdragon is the brand name of [SoCs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_on_a_chip) manufactured by Qualcomm and used on many Android devices. Codeaurora is the public forum to release updates for SoC components from Qualcomm: https://wiki.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QAEP. You can make a web search to know more.